# How to generate download file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, httpwebrequest

I'm creating asp.net special file manager. all file information saved to SQL Server table. My table is here

```
Table tFile(
FileID uniqueidentifier,
FileName nvarchar(50),
Extension nvarchar(50))
```

Upload process is: First i'm insert table row and then upload file to server. Then file renamed to FileID (GUID value). For example : 4a6327c4-0596-4949-a5f2-a639e934d534.JPG

Inserted table row is like this

`4a6327c4-0596-4949-a5f2-a639e934d534  | image1  |  JPG`

And file on the server like this

`www.domain.com/aa/Files/4a6327c4-0596-4949-a5f2-a639e934d534.JPG`

My problem is when i downloading current file, `4a6327c4-0596-4949-a5f2-a639e934d534.JPG` named file was downloaded. I need `image1.JPG`

When any user downloading current file, how to generate current file name to normal filename like 'image1.jpg'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a download.aspx page which takes the GUID of the image as a query string parameter. You can then lookup this value in the database to get the file path and send it to the browser like this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=image1.jpg");
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.WriteFile(pathToFileOnYourServer);
```

You can dynamically build the **filename=image1.jpg** part to call the image anything you like.

Comment: One small Caveat: If the filename ever contains spaces, it must be in double quotes, otherwise Firefox (3.6 at the time of writing) will fail to properly parse it - `attachment;filename="This is my Image1.jpg"` (Remember to escape " to \" in C# strings). Not sure if URL Encoding is another option.